# Force only one function of module to run at a time

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using Python and I have a swig interface to a c++ program. This program is a scientific application that also handles a database. We use it to fetch and save data, but the problem is that it does not support parallel calls. Meaning that if I try to spawn different threads from Python and call functions from this application it will throw an exception.

So my question is: Is there a way to "force" a python module to have a function executed only once at a time?

As I said normally we would fetch some data from this program, than do some number crunching and save the new data to the database the program holds. What I had in mind is wrapping this module some way that the functions would only run one at a time, so I can actually use more threads on the number crunching part of the program without having to worry about having two (or more) functions of this module being executed at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking fore is a [lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29). If you are using python's `threading`, you can simply use [threading.Lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

In the function that may only run once at a time, acquire the lock upon entry and release it just before the end `return` or the end of the function.